# Which day of the working week is called blue?

Tags: word-request

I heard that there is one, which is it? I couldn't find it. All I found was [*Blue Monday (date)* on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Monday_(date)) but here I am looking for a day of the week. Is there one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually got it. The day of the working week is ***Monday***. That's because after a nice weekend, people find it quite boring to go office and start working!

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/blue+monday) defines it:

> Blue Monday - *a Monday regarded as a depressing workday in contrast to the pleasant relaxation of the weekend.*

Note that the word *blue*, informally, here means [*sad (Sense #3)*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/blue_1). So, after having holidays for Saturday and Sunday, Monday is always sad to begin the work. :)

In fact, you do find articles on how to get rid of Monday Blues. One of the pages I found is on [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/jacquelynsmith/2013/02/25/11-ways-to-beat-the-monday-blues/).

Comment: It could be Monday, or it could be [Sunday](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_law), too.

Comment: @J.R. I don't think the given link has anything to do with what OP asked. He is quite specific about knowing the 'blue day' by relating it with 'working week'. I often keep my status 'Monday Blues' on Skype and Gtalk on Mondays that follows my last status of TGIF.

Comment: In a way, Sunday blue laws involve the working week, too. Anyhow, I didn't mean to start a debate; I just wanted to link to something that many ELLers might find interesting and related.